# White background appears on header while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, menu, header, scroll

There is a white background which stretches to the width of the screen when the page is scrolled to the end. http://freshpotsolutions.com/saudisurgeons.com/test11/
I would like to keep it with the same width throughout the page.

Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the menu element receives the `sticky` class, give it the same fixed width as `.theme-layout` (1230px) and remove the `left` attribute.

If an element with `position: fixed` has no left value, it will be automatically aligned to where it would be were it still part of the document flow. In order for it to have the correct width, you can no longer use a relative width of 100%, since its point of reference is now the document itself, not the layout container--you need to give it a fixed width.

Comment: i have updated the 'style.css' upon your instruction. half of the issue seems to be corrected now. But the header is still moving to right side when scrolled to the bottom.

Comment: That is because your `header.business1 .for-sticky.sticky` selector isn't strong enough. `#menu-sec` with its width of 100% is overwriting the width of 1230px. You could fix this by changing the selector to `header.business1 #menu-sec.for-sticky.sticky`.